# Socket.UseOnlyOverlappedIO?

Tags: c#, sockets

Does anyone know what Socket.UseOnlyOverlappedIO does, and if so, does it affect performance? There seems to be no real explanation on MSDN.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the old post but this caused me some issues!

The answer isn't correct, UseOnlyOverlappedIO (at least in .net 4) means that async calls (other that XXAsync) on the socket will not be bound to an IO completion port.

The value is ignored for the XXAsync calls which means that IO completion ports are always used so you can't do things like Duplicate the socket to another process.

Whether or not it will affect performance depends on your app, test it with both!

Answer (score 0):

It causes the socket to used [Overlapped I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O) instead of blocking.  On single processor/single core systems, this can lead to some performance benefits, but it tends to be less useful on multiprocessing systems.

Comment: Well, if you're deploying on a dual+ core machine, and using asynchonous sockets, it's useless.  On a single core, single processor machine, it's (theoretically) slightly faster for the asynchronous operations.

Comment: I probably wouldn't bother, though, since it's pretty much an edge case now, on nearly all hardware.

Comment: Do you have a link to something official that explains that? I would have expected the async operations to be using overlapped I/O anyway.

Comment: The Wikipedia article discusses it, but otherwise, search for OVERLAPPED on MSDN - there's quite a bit of discussion there.

Comment: Reed, actually I meant something official for "f you're deploying on a dual+ core machine, and using asynchonous sockets, it's useless. On a single core, single processor machine, it's (theoretically) slightly faster for the asynchronous operations"... I know what Overlapped I/O is...